# Excel: Filtering out specific Values in Table / Shortcode

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i got a pretty simple table with invoices. The data provided is *Invoice-Name, Date and amount*.
I now want to filter specific invoices by a shortcode (e.g. "MA") and copy only the invoices marked with "MA" into another table. I got that working already with an array formula.

But now i want to separate them by their dates. So all the invoces with shortcode "MA" and Date "January" should be copied into a new table.

How do i combine my current array formula with the filter of the date?

Here is my current formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$309,LARGE(($D$2:$D$309=$H$1)*(ROW($D$2:$D$309)-1),COUNTIF($D$2:$D$309,$H$1)+1-ROW(B1))),"")
```

I also added a [LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v0gfqxjqg47ph9m/CodeDemo.xlsx?dl=0) to a demo spreadsheet.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: Can't you just use `=FILTER(B2:C9,(MONTH(A2:A9)=1)*(D2:D9="MA"),"")` or don't you have MS365's `FILTER()`?

Comment: I really did not know about the Filter fuction! Problem solved! Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below formula-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$C$9,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$299)/(($D$2:$D$300="MA")*(MONTH($A$2:$A$300)=1)),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I did use `=FILTER()` in the end. That worked perfectly for my needs. Thank you for your answer!